# Structure Link List Segmentation-Fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I just got started on a lab of mine where I calculate the GPA of courses whose information is stored in a linked list of structures. As of now, I'm attempting to just print out all the course information to ensure that they have been properly initialized and added to the link list.

I'm running into a problem though because I keep getting a Segmentation Fault. I understand what the Segmentation Fault means, but I do not know where I am making my mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CLASSES 20


/* Function Prototypes */
struct course * initcourse( int, char *, char *, float, char *, char *);
void add( struct course * );

/* Definition of a data node holding course information */
  struct course {
    int term;
    char name[15];
    char abbrev[20];
    float hours;
    char grade [4];
    char type[12];
    struct course *next;
  };


/* head points to first node in list, end points to last node in list */
/* initializes both to NULL, no nodes yet */
struct course *head = (struct course *) NULL;
struct course *end = (struct course *) NULL;


/* Initializes a node, allocates memory for the node, and returns     */
/* a pointer to the new node. Must pass correct parameters.           */
struct course * initcourse( int term, char *name, char *abbrev, float hours, char *grade, char *type)
{
  struct course *ptr;
  ptr = (struct course *) calloc( 1, sizeof(struct course ) );
  if( ptr == NULL )

    return (struct course *) NULL;

  else
    {
      ptr->term = term;
      strcpy( ptr->name, name );
      strcpy( ptr->abbrev, abbrev );
      ptr->hours = hours;
      strcpy( ptr->grade, grade );
      strcpy( ptr->type, type );
      return ptr;
    }
}


/* This adds a node to the end of the list. You must allocate a node and */
/* then pass its address to this function                                */ 
void add(struct course *new)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    {
      head = new;
    }
  else
    {
      end->next = new;
      end = new;
    }
}

/* Prints all information in a node */
void printnode( struct course *ptr )
{
  printf("Term ->%d\n", ptr->term );
  printf("Name ->%s\n", ptr->name );
  printf("Abbreviation ->%s\n", ptr->abbrev );
  printf("Hours ->%f\n", ptr->hours );
  printf("Grade ->%s\n", ptr->grade );
  printf("Type ->%s\n", ptr->type );
}




/* Prints List of Nodes */
void printlist( struct course *ptr ) 
{ 
  while( ptr != NULL ) 
    { 
      printnode( ptr ); 
      ptr = ptr->next;  
    } 
} 

/* Calculates GPA */
/* float gpa ( struct course *ptr ) */
/* { */
/*   float totalhours; */
/*   float gpa; */
/*   float gradepoints; */

/*   while (ptr != NULL ) */
/*     { */
/*       totalhours += (ptr->hours); */
/*       gradepoints = (ptr->hours * ptr->grade); */
/*     } */
/*   gpa = (gradepoints /ptr->hours); */
/* } */



int main()
{

  int term;
  char name[15];
  char abbrev[20];
  float hours;
  char grade[4];
  char type[12];
  float gpa;
  struct course *ptr;

  struct course course1, course2, course3;

  course1.term = 1234;
  strcpy(course1.name,"cse1234");
  strcpy(course1.abbrev,"systems");
  course1.hours = 4;
  strcpy(course1.grade,"A");
  strcpy(course1.type,"GEC");


  ptr = initcourse(course1.term, course1.name, course1.abbrev, course1.hours, course1.grade, course1.type);

  struct course *head, *ptr2;
  head = ptr;
  // ptr2 = ptr;

  add(ptr);

  course2.term = 4332;
  strcpy(course2.name,"cse4332");
  strcpy(course2.abbrev,"Database");
  course2.hours = 4;
  strcpy(course2.grade,"B");
  strcpy(course2.type,"Technical");

  ptr2 =  initcourse(course2.term, course2.name, course2.abbrev, course2.hours, course2.grade, course2.type);

  add(ptr2);

  printlist(head);



}
```

Comment: seg fault = **use a debugger!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void add(struct course *new)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    {
      head = new;
    }
  else
    {
      end->next = new;
      end = new;
    }
}
```

You need to set `end` to `new` when inserting the first node (when `head == NULL`), otherwise you're dereferencing a null-pointer when adding further nodes.

And in `initcourse`, you ought to set the `next` member to `NULL`, since it is not guaranteed by the standard that all-bits-0 is a null-pointer representation (it *very* likely is, but there's no guarantee).

Also,

```
struct course *head, *ptr2;
head = ptr;
```

declares a new local variable `head` that shadows the global one, and instead of assigning directly to `head` (even though it's the wrong one), you should call `add(ptr);`.

Comment: thank you, that cleared up the problem.

I have another quick question (not sure if i should create a new post).

I'm trying to define each letter grade with the appropriate grade points. Where A = 4.0 B = 3.0

I know using the #define statement allows me to achieve this, but I am unable to define +/- . For example, "A-" should = 3.7. Is there a proper way to define all these letter grades? Is the "#define" directive the proper way to handle this task? Thanks for any help and I apologize if this is the incorrect place to ask this.

-Matt

Comment: You can't `#define` any name containing a '+' or a '-', so you need to take another path anyway. I'm not sure what the best way is, you have grades A to F, each with a possible + or -? Then a `switch` on the first `char` with a correction based on the second could be a way.

Answer (score 0):

You dont initialize the `next` pointer, so the last element contains a bad pointer, pointing to some garbage.

You also don't initialize `end`.

Another problem (not related to the crash) is that this code will create a duplicate entry:

```
head = ptr;
add(ptr);
```

There're other problems. You really should get a debugger and see what's going on.